# Difference between KLdiv(P||Q) and KLdiv(Q||P) in variational inference

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler, variational-inference

Variational inference is about finding an estimation Q(z) for the posterior P(Z|x).
According to all the variational inference papers, this is done by minimizing the KLdiv(Q||P). I want to understand why they choose to minimize this KL div and not the KLdiv(P||Q)? and how this choice is beneficial for variational inference?

Answer (score 1):

Both divergences are legitimate. In fact, they are members of a continuous family of divergences called the [$\alpha$-divergences](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.361.9105&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which all have their justifications.

If you look at the definition of the Kullback-Leibler divergence:
$$
\operatorname{KL}(Q\|P) = \int Q \log \frac{Q}{P}
$$

you see that the approximation $Q$ has to be zero whenever $P$ is zero, so this version is also sometimes called **zero-forcing**. This leads to approximations that underestimate the support $P$. E.g., approximating a Gaussian mixture $P$ with a single Gaussian $Q$ would lead to $Q$ choosing one of the components of the mixture and trying to approximate that one well while "ignoring" the others.

On the other hand, if you use $\operatorname{KL}(P\|Q)$, the same argument leads to a trend to overestimate the support of $P$. And the approximation of a Gaussian mixture $P$ with a single Gaussian $Q$ would lead to the Gaussian using a large variance to cover all the components of the mixture.

There is a nice visualization of the two above applications to Gaussian mixtures in [Bishop](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387310732) p.469, and I tried to reproduce it here. In the image, you see on the left side the zero-forcing and on the right side the zero-avoiding case. The black contours belong to the Gaussian mixture to approximate and the red contours belong to the single Gaussian approximation.

[image]

In summary, both versions have their virtues and usage depends on what you need.

Comment: thank you for. your help but you did not answer my question, I already know that but my probelem is why they choose reverse kl for variational inference and not the other version? so it is more about what is the use of this choice for variational inference and not in general

Comment: What I wanted to say is that there is no rule for only using one version and not the other. Both versions are used. And one way to decide between them is to determine which of the two cases in the image you prefer.

Comment: If you review the paper using variational inference, all of the are using the reverse kl div. So wanted to know why they are making this decision and how it benefits variational inference

Answer (score 0):

Posting this so that it may help future users, since OP was not satisfied with the other answer.

I believe that the reverse KL divergence is used since $Q(z)$ is usually known as it is some distribution selected from our variational family $\mathcal{Q}$, whereas the posterior is not known $P(z|x)$.

$D_{\operatorname{KL}}(Q(z)\parallel P(z|x))$ requires taking an expectation over $Q(z)$ which we know how to sample from. The reverse requires sampling from $P(z|x)$, which we cannot do for obvious reasons.